# Suppress Console Warnings for observe sequence

Tags: meteor

My docs each have a nested array with an `_id` field, which is required. This triggers the "duplicate Id in..." console warning. Pretty sure it's related to: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1980

Unfortunately, with about 50,000 docs being passed through (local data analysis, not a production app) all the console activity is starting to slow me down.

Is there a parameter to pass in to squelch console warnings or just a quick & dirty workaround? Nothing fancy/stable required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `console.warn = function () {}` to disable all warnings. But this will suppress all warnings, not just that particular warning, so that's not ideal.

If you look at the [ObserveSequence source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/observe-sequence/observe_sequence.js), you can see the code which does the warnings:

```js
var warn = function () {
  if (ObserveSequence._suppressWarnings) {
    ObserveSequence._suppressWarnings--;
  } else {
    if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && console.warn)
      console.warn.apply(console, arguments);

    ObserveSequence._loggedWarnings++;
  }
};
```

So setting `Package["observe-sequence"].ObserveSequence._suppressWarnings` to a large number will prevent that many warnings from `ObserveSequence`.

Comment: Brilliant! I saw the code but didn't even think to look in the `Packages` object. For future readers, I put a `Package["observe-sequence"].ObserveSequence._suppressWarnings = Infinity` at the top of my `onCreated` callback.